# Bitwise operation in C, referring to a position in an 8bit array

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am currently dealing with bitwise operations and I found a method, where the referencing to a position in an 8bit array is not clear for me.

Here is an example, the numbers are all chosen by me randomly just for the explanation, the method itself is much more complicated (the array can be initialised with any size big enough):

```
void method(int pos, uint8_t* array_of_num) {

  int dim = 5;
  uint8_t numbers[4] = {1, 8, 32, 64}; 

  int size = 10;
  int i = 0;
  for (i=0; i < size; i++){

     array_of_num[pos + i/4] |= numbers[i%4];   // <======
  }

}
```

I dont understand, to which position "array_of_num[pos + i/4]" refers to. array_of_num is an array of 8bit uints, so it looks like this:

```
[0] ----> 1 (00000001); 
[1] ----> 5 (00000101); 
[2] ----> ......
```

Is it referring to some bits of an int at a position in the array, but if yes, how can the --|-- operand only consider those bits, since the numbers[] are also 8bit uint. Let me try to explain what I mean by this example, so this:

```
pos = 0; i = 1
array_of_num[0 + 1/4] |= 00001000
```

wouldn't it be the same if we just write:

```
array_of_num[0] |= 00001000
```

Comment: It's `0 + i/4`  and not `0 + 1/4`.  ` i % 4`  is different from 0 if `i` is greater than 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the code is doing, is it's setting bits in the `array_of_num` array based on the given input (`size`, `pos`).

With the current values it starts with the 8 bit value at `pos`, sets bits 0, 3, 5 and 6 on, then moves to the next and does the same and for the third value it sets bits 0 and 3.

Written out it would be:

```
array_of_num[pos] | = 1;
array_of_num[pos] | = 8;
array_of_num[pos] | = 32;
array_of_num[pos] | = 64;
array_of_num[pos+1] | = 1;
array_of_num[pos+1] | = 8;
array_of_num[pos+1] | = 32;
array_of_num[pos+1] | = 64;
array_of_num[pos+2] | = 1;
array_of_num[pos+2] | = 8;
```

So in essence it's doing this:

```
array_of_num[pos] |= (1|8|32|64);
array_of_num[pos+1] |= (1|8|32|64);
array_of_num[pos+2] |= (1|8);
```

Of course `i = 0; array_of_num[0 + i/4]` is the same than `array_of_num[0]`, but when `i=6`, then it is something completely different. The divisor is used to make four or operations work on a single byte. and the modulo is used to point to only four values in the `numbers` array.

Comment: Ok, so If I understood correctly written like this, the counter `pos` will get increased after every 4 steps by one, I could also replace it by an additional counter and basically write `array_of_num[pos]`, right?

thank you a lot for your explanation!

Comment: Yes, the position is increased every 4 cycles, so it could be done with a separate counter also.